# I am having difficulty for multiple printing in scanner using array and if-else statement

Tags: java

I am having trouble about multiple printing using array, loops, and if-else statement

source code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter the number of players: ");
      int numplay = x.nextInt();
      int players[]= new int[numplay];
      int y; 


      for(int i=0; i < numplay; i++)
      {
          System.out.print("Goals score by player #"+ (i+1) +": ");
          y = x.nextInt();
          players[i]=y;

          if (players[i]<=10) 
          {
             System.out.println("Okay, fine, it's Messi");
          } 
          else 
          {
             System.out.println("Not Messi");
          }    
      }   

   }      
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of players: 3
Goals score by player #1: 2
Okay, fine, it's Messi
Goals score by player #2: 3
Okay, fine, it's Messi
Goals score by player #3: 4
Okay, fine, it's Messi
```

Possible output should be like this

```
Enter the number of players: 3
Goals score by player #1: 2
Goals score by player #2: 3
Goals score by player #3: 4
Okay, fine, it's Messi
```

Not Messi Situation:

```
Enter the number of players: 3
Goals score by player #1: 10
Okay, fine, it's Messi
Goals score by player #2: 13
Not Messi
Goals score by player #3: 2
Okay, fine, it's Messi
```

Not Messi Situation Possible Output:

```
  Enter the number of players: 3
    Goals score by player #1: 10
    Goals score by player #2: 13
    Goals score by player #3: 2
    Not Messi
```

P.S. I am practicing my array and I am having trouble with it.

Comment: For what scenarios are you printing the possible outputs?

Comment: The okay, fine, it's Messi should print if the score of all players were not exceeded in 10. But if it is exceeded in 10 the answer should me Not Messi

Comment: Please provide an example for which it would output `Not Messi`.

Comment: Hi! added it into my post the 'Not Messi' situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `boolean` flag which will be set if any of the players has number of goals greater than 10.

At the end, if the flag is set, it will output `Not Messi`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter the number of players: ");
      int numplay = x.nextInt();
      int players[] = new int[numplay];

      boolean exceededBy10 = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < numplay; i++)
      {
          System.out.print("Goals score by player #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
          players[i] = x.nextInt();

          if (players[i] > 10)
          {
              exceededBy10 = true;
          }    
      }   
      if (exceededBy10) {
          System.out.println("Not Messi");
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Okay, fine, it's Messi");
      }
   }      
}
```